# How to format linked R code in Latex so that it can be copied and run directly from the pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, code-formatting

I have to submit a programming assignment in pdf format (produced using LaTeX), and the tutor expects to be able to copy and paste the code directly from the pdf into R to run it. I know I can do this by hard-copying the code into the LaTeX document in a \verbatim block, but I usually use the 'listings' package to link my R source file directly to my LaTeX document, and when I do that, the pdf output contains a lot of extra spaces that are picked up when the code is copied back into R. Sometimes the code will still run with the spaces, but with decimal points, underscores etc the inserted space will cause problems. I've copied the same line from the 'verbatim' environment (top) and 'listings' (bottom) to illustrate the difference:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1), ps = 10, mar = c(3,3,2,2)) 

par ( mfrow = c(2 ,1) , ps = 10, mar = c(3 ,3 ,2 ,2))
```

I've been through the Source Codes documentation and tried removing whitespace and changing the basic style (my default is ttfamily), but this doesn't work, and Googling just brings me variations on the official documentation. Essentially, what I'd like to be able to do is apply the Verbatim font style to my Listings environment so that I can still format my code how I want to - but I suspect it won't be that easy. Any suggestions on how to get my R code into a document without copy-pasting each line, so that the output can be copied back into R, would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance...

Comment: Use R package knitr: http://kbroman.org/knitr_knutshell/pages/latex.html

Comment: There's something wrong with the tutor (or anyone else) who wants to copy from a PDF document.  Isn't there any way you can convince him to accept text files?

Comment: I completely agree. Unfortunately I have to include plots so that rules out text files - and it has to be submitted online in a single file (pdf, doc, docx, or txt). Which he will then download, and try to run the code in R. Since it's pointed me towards the extremely handy-looking knitr, I'm choosing to view this as a learning opportunity!

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution has been mentioned here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119218/how-to-copy-paste-from-lstlistings

Add

```
\lstset{columns=fullflexible}
```

and you will be able to copy/paste the R code from the pdf document.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @Roland, he has the right idea with knitr.

I would however also assume with enough configuration of `listings` in LaTeX you would be able to get rid of the unwanted whitespace. It's been a while since I fiddled with the `listings`, but I recall them having a lot of customisability, as well as syntax support for R, that should clear most of the conversion issues, but I may be mistaken.